# Proving the volume of sphere by using tiny volumes

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, volume

How can I prove the volume of sphere, by using many cones starting at the center of the sphere? It doesn't *have* to be cones, pyramids also work.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula of the volume in spherical coordinates 
$$
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\int_0^R\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta =
\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi\frac{R^3}3\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\theta,
$$

$$\frac{R^3}3\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\theta = \frac13(R^2\sin\phi\,d\phi\,d\theta)R$$
can be interpreted as $\frac13$(area of base)(height) of an infinitesimal pyramid.